# Space child nodes equally in mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I'm just starting with mindmaps. How can I make the child nodes in the following code spaced equally around the root node? At the moment they are all squeezed at the bottom.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap] 
\node[concept] {Root concept}
    child {node[concept] {Child concept}} 
    child {node[concept] {Child concept}}
    child {node[concept] {Child concept}}
    child {node[concept] {Child concept}}
    child {node[concept] {Child concept}}   
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `clockwise from` or `counterclockwise from`. Also `sibling angle` may be important.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,concept color=yellow] 
\node[concept] {Root concept}
    [clockwise from=0,level 1 concept/.append style={sibling angle=72}]
    child {node[concept] {Child concept}} 
    child {node[concept] {Child concept}}
    child {node[concept] {Child concept}}
    child {node[concept] {Child concept}}
    child {node[concept] {Child concept}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]